# To show that a natural transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Given a natural transformation $\tau$ from a functor $D$ to a functor $E$ where each functor is from a category $G$ to a category $C$, in order to show that if each $\tau_x$ is an isomorphism, then $\tau$ is an isomorphism, one needs to show that $\tau_y{D(u)} = E(u)\tau_x$ implies $\tau_y^{-1}E(u) = D(u)\tau_x^{-1}$ for all $x,y$ in $G$. So I managed to show that $\tau_y{D(u)} = E(u)\tau_x$ implies $\tau_y^{-1}E(u) = D(u)\tau_x^{-1}$ for all $x,y$ in $G$. But how does this prove that $\tau$ is an isomorphism?

A natural transformation $\tau:D \to E$ is defined as the collection of all morphisms $\tau_x:D(x) \to E(x)$ where $x$ is an object in $G$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $\tau_y^{-1}$ if $\tau$ is not an isomorphism ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Hi, I am trying to show that if each $r_y^{-1}$ is an isomorphism then $\tau$ is also an isomorphism. I will edit the questions. Thanks.

Comment: It is the same problem. Do you assume that $\tau_y^{-1}$ is defined ? Note that it is the same as $\tau_y$ beiing an isomoprhism

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Oh yes, sorry I meant $\tau_y$. I am assuming each $\tau_y$ is an isomorphism then would like to show that $\tau$ is an isomorphism. I can do the converse but this one seems harder.

Comment: OK sorry I misread your comment. You're stuck on $gD = E h$ implies $Dh^ {-1} = g^{-1} E$ ?

Comment: multpliply on the left by something to make the $g$ disappears

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Thanks then how does $Dh^{-1} = g^{-1}E$ imply that $\tau$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is about what is an invertible natural transformation. By definition of an isomorphism in the category $[G,C]$ (the category of functors from $G$ to $C$), a natural transformation $\tau : D \to E$ is invertible if and only if it exists $\sigma: E \to D$ such that $\tau\sigma = \mathrm{id}_E$ and $\sigma\tau = \mathrm{id}_D$. The claim is that if each of the $\tau_x$ are isomorphisms in $E$, then the collection
$$ \left({\tau_x}^{-1}:E(x)\to D(x) \right)_{x\in G} $$
is a good candidate for the wanted $\sigma$.

What you already proved is that indeed this collection is a natural transformation. Now we need to prove that $\tau\sigma = \mathrm{id}_E$ and $\sigma\tau = \mathrm{id}_D$. What is the composite of two natural transformations? By definition it is the collection of the component-wise composite. So in our case we end up with:
$$ \tau\sigma = \left(E(x) \overset {{\tau_x}^{-1}} \to D(x) \overset{{\tau_x}} \to E(x)\right)_{x\in G} \quad \text{and} \quad \sigma\tau = \left(D(x) \overset {{\tau_x}} \to E(x) \overset{{\tau_x}^{-1}} \to D(x)\right)_{x\in G} $$

I let you take it from here!

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that the following square commutes:

\begin{array}{c} Ex & \overset{\tau_x^{-1}}\rightarrow & Dx \\ Ff\downarrow  && \downarrow Gf \\ Ey & \underset{\tau_y^{-1}}\rightarrow & Dy \end{array}

Now, $Gf\circ \tau_x^{-1}=\tau_y^{-1}\circ Ff\Leftrightarrow Gf=\tau_y^{-1}\circ Ff\circ \tau_x\Leftrightarrow \tau_y\circ Gf=Ff\circ \tau_x,\ $ which is a naturality  square for $\tau,\ $ which is known to commute:

\begin{array}{c} Dx & \overset{\tau_x}\rightarrow & Ex \\ Gf\downarrow  && \downarrow Ff \\ Dy & \underset{\tau_y}\rightarrow & Ey \end{array}

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how this result implies that $\tau$ (which is the collection of all $\tau_x$) is an isomorphism.

Comment: Join the two naturality squares and use the definition of isomorphism in the functor category $C^G.$